# Get hidden fields from currently clicked td and first td of the current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, hidden

*Consider a scenario*

I have one table and having 8 columns, Each columns have some number of hidden fields - let's say 5 hidden fields.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all the hidden fields' value when I click on particular cell and I also want hidden values from the first td of the currently clicked row from [cell]

## Things achieved

I'm able to get the hidden field values of the currently clicked row cell's first child like following

```
element.closest("tr").find("td:first").find("input:hidden")
```

This will reult 3 as the first cell will always have 3 inputs.

## Where I am stuck:

I'm getting the first cell's hidden inputs value but not able to get hidden inputs value of  currently clicked cell.

**Here is the sample HTML**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;">4th Class( A ) 
         <input id="SectionID" name="SectionID" type="hidden" value="7">
         <input id="SectionDetailID" name="SectionDetailID" type="hidden" value="1">
         <input id="SectionName" name="SectionName" type="hidden" value="4th Class( A ) ">
      </td>
      <td class="cells" onclick="fetchData(this);">
         <div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Name:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">P D S</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Sub:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">Hindi</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Period:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">Period 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">From:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">11:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">To:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">12:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Year:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">2014</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <input id="TimeTableDtlID" name="TimeTableDtlID" type="hidden" value="1">
         <input id="TimeTableHdrID" name="TimeTableHdrID" type="hidden" value="7">
         <input id="PeriodID" name="PeriodID" type="hidden" value="38">
         <input id="PeriodName" name="PeriodName" type="hidden" value="Period 2">
         <input id="PeriodFromTime" name="PeriodFromTime" type="hidden" value="11:00">
         <input id="PeriodToTime" name="PeriodToTime" type="hidden" value="12:00">
         <input id="TTYear" name="TTYear" type="hidden" value="2014">
         <input id="SubjectName" name="SubjectName" type="hidden" value="Hindi">
      </td>
      <td class="cells" onclick="fetchData(this);">
         <div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Name:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">J P Pl</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Sub:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">English</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Period:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">Period 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">From:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">11:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">To:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">12:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataRow">
               <div class="cellLabel">Year:</div>
               <div class="cellValue">2014</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <input id="TimeTableDtlID" name="TimeTableDtlID" type="hidden" value="3">
         <input id="TimeTableHdrID" name="TimeTableHdrID" type="hidden" value="7">
         <input id="PeriodID" name="PeriodID" type="hidden" value="38">
         <input id="PeriodName" name="PeriodName" type="hidden" value="Period 2">
         <input id="PeriodFromTime" name="PeriodFromTime" type="hidden" value="11:00">
         <input id="PeriodToTime" name="PeriodToTime" type="hidden" value="12:00">
         <input id="TTYear" name="TTYear" type="hidden" value="2014">
         <input id="SubjectName" name="SubjectName" type="hidden" value="English">
      </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
function fetchData(element) {
   var $element = $(element);
   var objHidden = [];
   console.log($element.closest("tr").find('td:first').andSelf().find("input:hidden").length); // Returns 19 Where it must be 11
   $element.closest("tr").find('td:first').andSelf().find("input:hidden").each(function (i, elem) {
      objHidden[elem.getAttribute("name")] = elem.value;
   });
   console.log(objHidden); // Getting same values always
}
```

### Fiddle DEMO

**EDIT**

*It's Simple scenario when I click on cell means `TD` except the first one, I want hidden values from the currently clicked cells and also hidden values from the first `TD` in current row which is not clicked.*

**How to get hidden fields of currently clicked cell and hidden fields of the closest row's first td?**

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`andSelf` and the last jQuery object into the current stack. But if we look closely at your line :

```
$element.closest("tr").find('td:first').andSelf().find("input:hidden")
```

You do `.closest().find().andSelf()`. So that mean `andSelf` return the `.closest('tr')`.

Try to use `add` instead :

```
$element.closest("tr").find('td:first').add($element).find("input:hidden")
```

Alternatively, you could use that as well :

```
$element.siblings(":first").andSelf().find("input:hidden");
```

Comment: Bull's Eye.. You nailed It.. Thanks Friend. :)

Comment: Upvoted for being able to do it on a single line; didn't think it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery documentation on `andSelf()`:

> When one of the DOM traversal methods is called, the new set of elements is pushed onto the stack. If the previous set of elements is desired as well, .addBack() can help

So your query for:

```
$element.closest("tr").find('td:first').andSelf()
```

is actually returning not just the content of `td:first`, but also the content of the *previous set of elements* - which is the `tr`, not the element you originally clicked. Hence, you are getting all 19 hidden `input` elements, not just the 3 from the first cell and the 8 from the current.

*[Edit - removed possible solution, the accepted answer is significantly neater than mine]*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for so heres a quick demonstration of JQuery selectors running on your HTML to get certain parts.

http://jsfiddle.net/x3HN3/3/
(Click a cell and check log);

Please give some comment on what exactly you want from these fields..

```
$('table tr>td').click(function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).parents('tr');
    console.log(currentRow);
    var currentCell = $(this);
    console.log(currentCell);
    var currentCellHtml = $(this);
    console.log(currentCellHtml);
    var numberOfHiddenCtrlsWithinCell = $(this).find(':input:hidden');
    console.log(numberOfHiddenCtrlsWithinCell);
    var numberOfHiddenCtrlsWithinRow = currentRow.find(':input:hidden');
    console.log(numberOfHiddenCtrlsWithinRow);
});
```

From these variables you can get whatever you need using jquery selectors.. for example, to get the first table cell's html from the current clicked cell's row you'd do 
`currentRow.find('td:first').html();`

Comment: That is Ok. It's Simple scenario when i click on cell means `TD` except the first one, i want hidden values from the currently clicked cells and also hidden values from the first `TD` which is not clicked

Comment: cant understand you man sorry.. :/  http://jsfiddle.net/x3HN3/4/ that'll get the values for u but i really dunno what you need.. :(

Comment: Thank you friend. I've found solution.